# populating a select tag using struts2 jquery plugin

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a jsp that contains a struts2-jquery-plugin select tag that loads its data dynamically by sending an ajax request as follows:

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="providerList"/>
<sj:select href="%{remoteurl}" id="provider" name="language"
                            list="pList"
                            listKey="myKey"
                            listValue="myValue"
                            emptyOption="true"
                            headerKey="-1"
                            headerValue="Select" label="Provider"/>
```

Now when ajax request is made, control goes to action codes as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> pList=new ArrayList<String>(); 
public ArrayList<String> getpList() {
    return pList;
}
public void setpList(ArrayList<String> pList) {
    this.pList = pList;
}
public String providerList() {
    pList.add("ASC");
    pList.add("asas");
    pList.add("asasasas");
    return "returnedList";
}
```

In my struts.xml, correponding to actiion providerList, if i specify the result type as dispatcher then it takes the control to a jsp. What i wish is to just make the list pList reach the dropdown list of select tag.

Now the problem is that i want my select tag to be populated with this pList values. How should i configure this providerList action in struts.xml file. or i do i also need to make any changes in my action method ,in return type or anything. As far as i know i can use return type as json . Is there any other solution except json.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no other solution than JSON, if you're relying on that tag.

In order for the `sj:select` tag to work, you have to remove the below from the `sj:select`

```
 listKey="myKey"
 listValue="myValue"
```

Since, what you're sending from action is a list of string, but in the JSP it's expecting a map or a bean because of the above two properties.

In struts.xml, you have to configure the result type to be json and in order to do that we have to include [struts2-json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html) in the project.

Comment: Sir can u please provide me the that struts.xml configuration code. I have tried a number of things but i fail to implement it. I am actually new to web devt. Its my 1st app only.

Comment: I use maven! but here are a few old examples - https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples